# Find Matrix C relating two symmetric matrices A and B (Such that AC = B)

Tags: linear-algebra

I will be grateful if someone can guide me through the following problem:

So I have two matrices, $A$ and $B$:

- Matrix $A$ is $N\times N$, symmetric, does not have any zero element and non-invertible.
- Matrix $B$ is $N\times N$, symmetric, does not have any zero element and non-invertible.

I want to Find Matrix $C$ [which is $N\times N$] such that:
$$AC = B$$

Is there a way to find a closed-form solution to $C$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am asking this question as a modification to a previous one that does not seem to have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions of symmetry and not having zero elements are not relevant.  A necessary and sufficient condition is that the column space of $A$ contains the column space of $B$.  If so, you can take $C = A^+ B$
where $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the Feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in building $C$ as the [Procrustes approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) of $A$ and $B$.

$
\begin{equation}
P = A^TB\\
U\Sigma V= \text{SVD}(P) \\
C = UV^T \\
\end{equation}
$